# Publish in DNS that all mail is S/MIME?

Tags: email, dns, smime

Just as we can indicate through [ADSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Author_Domain_Signing_Practices) that all our mail should be expected to have a DKIM signature, is there a standard way to indicate in a DNS record that all our mail will have an S/MIME signature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

There's a bit of a problem of communication between layers in there. DKIM is a technology that allows the MTA for a domain to sign all email originating from that domain under the control of the domain's administrator. S/MIME and PGP are technologies that enable the end user to sign all outgoing email. The domain administrator has no say in the matter: they, or an MTA they control, cannot sign the email even if they wanted to. Therefore the domain administrator cannot guarantee that all email originated from the domain is S/MIME or PGP signed. It all depends on the MUA that each individual end user is using. If no such guarantee can exist then there is no point in supporting the ability to publish such a guarantee in DNS.